# PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject Error

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/rhpl/_pjac.so: undefined
symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject
```

I am using the Python version 2.7.

Well, all apps don't produce same error but similar errors. All undefined
symbols start with PyUnicodeUCS4.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Since this answer was the still the on google front page for this error, I'll post something that worked for me when

```
from lxml import etree
```

produced an error message **undefined symbol: "PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject"**
when on a compiled-from-source python 2.7.13

I reconfigured with the following flag

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

The error went away for me. 
Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: Ah! This means that the package and Python itself were compiled with conflicting settings.